# Wordpress. How to use shortcode with if else statement?

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, shortcode

I have following code but it's displaying shortcode in text rather than showing results of shortcode.

```
$curr_user_id = get_current_user_id();
// the value is 0 if the user isn't logged-in
if ( $curr_user_id != 0 ) {
    // we know now the user is logged-in, so we can use his/her ID to get the user meta
    $um_value = get_user_meta( $curr_user_id, 'user_phone', true );
    // now we check if the value is correct
    if ( ! empty( $um_value ) && $um_value == 'French' ) {
        // if so we can output something
        echo '[ld_course_list course_category_name="french" col=4 progress_bar=true]';
    } else {
    // else the code, eg.
    echo '[ld_course_list course_category_name="english" col=4 progress_bar=true]';
}
}
```

Above code will result in text below rather than showing results of the shortcode

> [ld_course_list course_category_name="english" col=4
>   progress_bar=true]

How do I change my code so it actually runs shortcode?

Thank you.

**Following code worked. Only problem is do_shortcode is breaking stylesheet. Anyone know why or how to fix it?**

```
<?
$curr_user_id = get_current_user_id();
// the value is 0 if the user isn't logged-in
if ( $curr_user_id != 0 ) {
    // we know now the user is logged-in, so we can use his/her ID to get the user meta
    $um_value = get_user_meta( $curr_user_id, 'user_phone', true );
    // now we check if the value is correct
    if ( ! empty( $um_value ) && $um_value == 'French' ) {
        // if so we can output something
        echo do_shortcode('[ld_course_list course_category_name="french" col=4 progress_bar=true]');
    } else {
    // else the code, eg.
    echo do_shortcode('[ld_course_list course_category_name="english" col="4" progress_bar="true"]');
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using it in wrong way, the method you are trying is used inside wordpress pages, posts etc.

To use inside plugin, theme or any other `.php` file, use WordPress function called `do_shortcode()` that lets you add shortcodes directly in your themes and plugins.

Add it like this:

`echo do_shortcode("[ld_course_list course_category_name="english" col=4 progress_bar=true]");`

Comment: sorry...I got it. echo do_shortcode('[ld_course_list course_category_name="english" col=4 progress_bar=true]'); worked.

Comment: First, test your shortcode inside wordpress page/post to see; if it works or not. Secondly enable debug mode to get the error message. Third, where are you trying to use this code? (`functions.php`, plugin, theme)

Comment: I accepted your answer..thank you. Only problem is do_shortcode is breaking css file so it's looking weird. Is this common problem?

Comment: no it's not common and it's obviously not because of using `do_shortcode`. It's highly likely that the content of shortcode css is causing issues with page css. You would need to investigate conflicting rules and fix them.

Comment: I am using PHP Snipplets to add php code into wordpress page. Could that be why? How would I add above code as function and call it from a page?

Comment: no matter where you use this shortcode, it cannot cause css conflict. However, the content it displays can have conflicting css. You would need to check and fix it.

Comment: I think PHP Snippets that I am using to insert about code directly into Wordpress page is causing the problem. How do I change code so that I use function and call it to wordpress page without using plugin like PHP Snippets

Comment: define a new function, put all above code inside that. Then register new shortcode and use that shortcode inside page. [Adding shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/add_shortcode) In this way, you won't need to use plugin.